# Regular expression for Primary and Unique key

Tags: java, javascript, regex

What will be the Regular expression to find PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE KEY  ::

Sample create query:

```
CREATE TABLE `empiccrdb` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ccrId` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` MEDIUMTEXT,
  `delflag` TINYINT(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `isEncrypted` TINYINT(2) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ccrId` (`ccrId`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=829 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: are you perchance parsing an SQL file?

Comment: `(PRIMARY|UNIQUE) KEY`. Or can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Stop. Just don't. This isn't going to work. Find another way.

Comment: @Zutty That comment would be more helpful if you suggested a better approach...

Comment: You've tagged this question "java" and "javascript". Which is it?

Comment: We don't know what they are trying to do, do we?

Comment: as an result i am looking for id and ccrId which is primary and unique key

Comment: and how are regular expressions supposed to help here?

Comment: i have create SQL as string and from that i need to determine primary|unique key

Comment: i can parse this regex either from JS or Java

Comment: @Keppil you solution won't work thanks for reply

Comment: @TusharTrivedi which rdbms do you use ? which sql dialect ? what is the source of your sql (free-form vs. program [which one?] output, ie. human- or machine-generated) ? in general your approach is not recommended, in particular as the keywords you are testing against may appear in string literals of the sql clause(s). it will be very tricky to distinguish these cases and most certainly impossible with a _maintainable_ regex.

Comment: @TusharTrivedi can't you query the data dictionary for the information? execute the create statement, query the dd for all the info you need, delete the table. this procedure will have the additional advantage of a general syntax check for free.

Comment: *"i have create SQL as string and from that i need to determine primary|unique key"* please show an example of the sql you create. if you create an ´insert´ statement then you won't find an `id` in that string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, as the comments on your question suggest, it's often wisest to avoid String parsing / processing other code unless you absolutely have to.

It throws up complications in the build process and issues for future change control.

Perhaps you are better to talk to the database, determine the table structure and find the keys from there?

Having said that, here is a java regex that could help you:

```
    String sql = "... put it here ...";

    String regex = "(PRIMARY|UNIQUE) KEY[ `a-zA-z]+\\(`([a-zA-Z]+)`\\)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(sql);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + ": " + matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Comment: For the love of God I do hope you also read all the comments and take them seriously. This is such a Bad Idea(tm) it could give the atomic bomb a run for its money.